# Expected temeplate-name before '<' token

Tags: c++, qt, include

In QT creator, I am developing a program in QT and need to include the following files:

- QPtrList.h
- QPtrQueue.h
- QString.h

However these files do not seem to be present and I am getting this error:

> Expected temeplate-name before '<' token

Is there anyway to add these files to my installation of QT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use QT4.8 or QT5 (5 is better)

`QPtrList.h` and `QPtrQueue.h` are not supported by QT4.8 and QT5.

Use `#include <QList>` instead of `QPtrList.h`

Use `#include <QQueue>` instead of `QPtrQueue.h`

Example "console" in QT5:

```
#include <QList>
#include <QQueue>
#include <QString>

#include <QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Pro file:

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = untitled8
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
```